# Python print use '' instead of ()

Tags: python

i'm reading a python file were the author use '' instead of () to call print statments, for example:

```
print 'Install the following library to make this script work'
print 'Impacket : https://github.com/CoreSecurity/impacket.git'
print 'PyCrypto : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto'
```

those are some lines of the code mentioned before.

Mi question is if this form to use print is correct or i'm missing something.

Comment: That's an old syntax for Python 2, we are now in Python 3.9. If you are new and want to learn python I recommend this [website](https://www.w3schools.com/python/)

Comment: @AndréClérigo is correct. As we are now in Python 3, we'll need those parentheses **with** the quotes (not **instead**): such as the following: `print('Hello World')`

Comment: The `'` marks aren't being used to call `print`. Those are being used to delimit strings. You'd need them in the Python 3 equivalent of this code too.

Answer (score 2):

That was Python 2. The most obvious breaking change in Python 3 was making `print` a proper function. Python 2 is deprecated; you should only be using Python 3 now and so should be forced to write

```
print('Install the following library to make this script work')
print('Impacket : https://github.com/CoreSecurity/impacket.git')
print('PyCrypto : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto')
```

Comment: actually he was asking about what he read and whether this was correct or not, he seems to actually know that print uses paranthesis

Comment: Also, `print` may have been obvious, but it was one of the easier parts of the change; the `2to3` fixer could convert `print`s from old to new syntax automatically. The change from `str`/`unicode` to `bytes`/`str` (including necessary changes to literal syntax) and from `int / int` meaning the same as `int // int` to it being "true" (floating point for `int`s) division were the hardest to deal with by far (because the correct fix was logic dependent, and couldn't be derived automatically from syntax analysis).

Answer (score 0):

Python print syntax changed from 2.x to 3.x.

Python 2.x syntax

```
print "something"
```

Python 3.x

```
print("something")
```